# Upload PNG Attachment ALM 12.60 rest

Tags: image, upload, png, hp-uft, alm

Good morning,
I am trying to upload an image (PNG) through ALM Api rest.
This is the function:

```
Function uploadFicheroALM(nombreScript, rutaFichero, executionId, value)
    leerConfiguracion
    readContextoEjecucion
    inicializarDatosALM
    nombreFichero = rutaFichero
    sBoundary = "--a123b"
    
    contenidoFichero = URLEncode(convertirBase64("C:/Users/User/Desktop/prueba.png"))
    
    requestUrl = almUrl&"/qcbin/rest/domains/"&almDominio&"/projects/"&almProyecto&"/runs/"&executionId&"/attachments"
    'vbCrLf = salto de linea
    auth = Base64Encode(almUser&":"&almPass)
    
    Set o = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    o.open "POST", requestUrl, false
    o.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic "&auth
    o.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=a123b"
    
    'Description
    request = request & sBoundary & vbCrLf
    request = request & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""description""" & vbCrLf
    request = request & "Descripcion de prueba" & vbCrLf
    
    'File Name
    request = request & sBoundary & vbCrLf
    request = request & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""filename""" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    request = request & "prueba.png" & vbCrLf
    
    'File Name
    request = request & sBoundary & vbCrLf
    request = request & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""override-existing-attachment""" & vbCrLf
    request = request & "y" & vbCrLf
    
    'File
    request = request & sBoundary & vbCrLf
    request = request & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""file""" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    request = request & "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" & vbCrLf
    request = request & contenidoFichero & vbCrLf
    request = request & "--a123b--"
    
    o.send request
    
    respuesta = o.responseText 
End Function
```

It can report "description", "filename" and "image" as you can see in the capture:

[image: Error to open the image]

But If I open the picture shows an "Unkown file error", Can anyone help me?, Thanks in advance.